# How to make servos not jitter without extra hardware

Tags: gpio, servo, real-time

To control a servo, I'm using [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=46771). To summarize it: you use code like this:

```
while True:
   GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)  
   time.sleep(0.0015)  
   GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)  
   time.sleep(0.0185)
```

Note that the `0.0015` and `0.0185` change based on the desired angle.
One issue they said about was that the servo may jitter if the program is run normally. Its because a regular program will have imprecise timing.

My question is, how does one make the timing more precise so the servo does not jitter? (It said something about kernel priorities and such.)

Comment: What is *this*.  There are several possible solutions mentioned in that thread.  Which are you using?

Comment: Ditto.  Please do not ask people to go read an entire thread somewhere else in order to try and help *you*.  Ping me when you've clarified that and I'll reopen this.

Comment: @joan Sorry, I just added a summary.

Comment: The example code in your question is using software timing to generate the pulses. That will be subject to jitter depending on what else is happening on the system. Jitter will make the servos twitch (and possibly reduce the servo's working life).  There should have been examples of hardware timing in that thread.  Have a look at my [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) and servoblaster.

Comment: One possible solution is to use a Servo Controller IC ... see:

http://www.adafruit.com/products/815